# Slow query due to IP address in statement with Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

We're having a slow query problem with SQL server.

We have some software which is using a virtual host name of the SQL Server Listener in the query and this is causing slow query performance.

```
UPDATE table SET
       status = 1
FROM  [HOSTNAMEOFSQLLISTENER].database.dbo.things AS things
WHERE bar = foo
```

Looking at the execution plan it's spending all it's time in the "Remote Scan" stage, I'm not sure why this would be.

The weird thing is when running the below query, replacing the IP address of the listener with the IP address of the SQL server the listener points to (and I've made sure it's the same server you end up on if you connect to SQL server via the listener through the management studio) the execution plan is sensible (uses indexes) and the query completes in a fraction of the time.

```
UPDATE table SET
       status = 1
FROM  [HOSTNAMEOFSQLSERVERDIRECTLY].database.dbo.things AS things
WHERE bar = foo
```

Apparently this behaviour isn't a problem in SQLServer2008 but I haven't had this confirmed yet.

So I have two questions:

1) Why is the execution plan different?

2) Is putting the IP address of the listener considered best practice in these scenarios?

Cheers

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to being unable to read the table statistics on the linked server, so the query optimizer has no clue where to start. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/07/21/performance-impact-linked-server-security-configuration-and-how-it-can-hurt-you.aspx

If you aren't really passing data back and forth, the first thing to try is to encapsulate the UPDATE in a stored proc.